# Multiple db queries curb PHP SQL

Tags: php, sql, database

So, I have 2 tables in my database - in the first one I have all the users and in the second one - topics they started (on forum). I wanted to allow users to have their favourite topics so I created column 'favourites' in 'users' table.

Favourite topics identificators are saved sequentally and they're separated with | char (e.g. 5321|3321|1234).

And it works fine but when I want to show all user's favourites, I need to get values from other table for every topic separately (title, content etc.) but I feel it's too big server usage, especially if user has a lot of favourites.

Hope you can help me,

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What queries have you tried? This seems the perfect job for a join or in

Comment: Simply `SELECT * FROM topics WHERE link = :link` for every favourite.

Comment: You shouldn't use a text column to store multiple ids, they have a major impact on performance and don't guarantee that the ids exist. You should create a new table with the relation between users and favourites

Comment: So I should create relational table _favourites_?

Comment: yes, that table should contain the user id and the topic